# evaluate individual numbers within an integer to determine the even count

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program I am supposed to code for asks for a user input (can be a decimal or not) and then the function is supposed to ignore any numbers after the decimal and count how many of the numbers within the integer are even numbers. So far what I have done (I don't even know if this was the best or correct way to go about the problem) is have the user input be a string, not an integer or float, then find the decimal and assign this new number to a new variable. 
What I'm having trouble with is looping through each individual number to determine if its even or not. It won't allow me to convert it to an integer before the loop because it says integers can't be iterated, and when i do it within the loop it also gives me an error.

```
digit_input=(input("Enter a number:"))

def digit_count(digit_input): 
    i = 0 
    even_count = 0
    start = digit_input.find(".", i)
    new_num=(digit_input[:start])
    while i < len(new_num):
      new=int(new_num[i])
      if new % 2 == 0:
        even_count += 1
        return even_count
      else: 
        break 
      i+=1

print(digit_count(digit_input))
```

What I currently have does tell me whether or not the first integer is even or not. But if, for instance, I input 222 it tells me there's only 1 even integer

***** If there's a better way to do this feel free to tell me. I am new to python and this was the only way I could think of.

Comment: Couldn't you straight away convert the input to an integer instead of dealing with the decimal point?

Comment: Part of the prompt wants the program to only deal with numbers before the decimal. I personally don't know how to do that if I convert it to a integer right away. If you do please tell me so I can learn as I am new to python

Answer (score 2):

Beside the fact that there are certainly faster or more elegant ways to do that, the following changes will fix your code. Don't return after the first even digit, keep counting:

```
while i < len(new_num):
  new = int(new_num[i])
  if new % 2 == 0:
    even_count += 1  # do not return meaningless count now!
  # do not break otherwise, keep counting
  i += 1
return even_count  # but return count after finishing counting
```

Consider, for instance, this one-liner:

```
def digit_count(digit_input):
  return sum(1 for d in s.split('.', 1)[0] if not int(d) % 2)
  # or with a little type coercing trickery and purely string ops:
  # return sum(d in '02468' for d in s.split('.', 1)[0])
```

Comment: I mean I'm sure there are better ways, but I don't know how to go about doing them. If you could point me in the right (or better) direction that'd be great.

Comment: @NouraAsrar Added a shorter solution

Comment: thank you! but how come it says invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Comment: That will happen if your input contains non-digits. The `int` conversion will fail in that case. My second suggestion (uncommented) is more robust in that way.

Comment: I'm talking about the one-liner you suggested. That one is giving me an error.

Comment: Me too, that one-liner contains an `int` conversion, too ;) check the additional suggestion (`# ....`) which can deal with non-digits as well!

Answer (score 0):

In a one liner you could do this

```
n_even_before_decimal = len(list(x for x in digit_input.split('.')[0] if int(x)%2 == 0))
```

This code assumes you have the number the user input, having a decimal point as a string in the `digit_input` variable

**Explanation**

The code inside the `list` function is just iterating over all of the characters before the '.' (denoted as `[0]` of the `split` function) converts them into `int`s and checks if they are even.
It saves them all to a list and counts the length at the end.